# Free alternatives to Tivoli Enterprise Console

Tags: monitoring, logging, tivoli

I'm looking for a free solution that allows operators to keep an eye on systems *and* applications.  It should digest log files from different sources and allow for alerts to be triggered in certain conditions.

I guess this is a trivial question for most of you, but I am less familiar with these types of applications.

Thank you!
J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask anyone in the game about monitoring, and they're bound to mention [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/). On of the great things about Nagios is that it is simply a scheduling and reporting engine. Its trivial to write plugions to monitor the things you want to measure - and [lots of people have done that](http://exchange.nagios.org/) or to put new front ends on. [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) provide a nicely packaged verion.

There are probably plugins for log analysis (a quick goole turned up [this](http://nordicmeetonnagios.op5.org/op5media/nmn2009/presentations/Balasz%20Scheidler%20-%20syslog-ng-3.0.pdf)) but writing your own is easy. Alternatively (or in addition) you might want to have a look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) which is specifically a tool for manipulating log files.

Comment: just wanted to point out that zabbix is not a repackage of nagios, it is a full standalone monitoring product :)

Answer (score 2):

Or, as an alternative, you could look at [Icinga](http://www.icinga.org), which is a fork of Nagios.

Answer (score 1):

Tivoli Enterprise Console is also a "rules engine" which Nagios is not. Freely available, open source alternatives to that are [ZenOSS](http://community.zenoss.org/index.jspa) and [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/about/) (you would have to add it yourself).